# Cannot access rpi's apache2 local server by local domain name on Android

Tags: android, apache, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have a local apache web server running on my LAN, hosted by my Raspberry Pi. I can connect to the web server using IP address `192.168.1.6` or my raspberry's machine name `raspberrypi.local` using apple devices or raspberry itself. But when I try to access the web server through raspberry's machine name on an Android web browser, it fails to find the DNS Server but it works fine through its IP Address

Comment: Is DNS address at android device is correct? You can check it in connection settings.

Comment: Try this I was having the same issues too https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=267113